# Print a list after updating 1 to odd elements in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, addition

```
ls=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in ls:
     if(i%2!=0):
         i=i+1
         print i
```

I am getting the answer separately like 2,4,6,8,10. I am not getting the list.please help?
I am new to python.I don't know much about the packages and I am using python 2.7.1.

any other keyword or method other than append?? Thank you

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on your goal, but I can see that you're printing individual numbers.  To print a list, you must add those numbers to a list, then print it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason each element is printing on a separate line is because you're printing `i` at each stage of your loop. In this context, `i` refers at every step to an index within your list `ls`, so it's never going to contain all the values you want from your list.

If you wanted to print only the odd elements from your list, you should create an empty list and add to it within your loop:

```
new_list = []

for i in ls:
    if(i % 2 == 1):
        new_list.append(i + 1)

print new_list
```

Or you could use a list comprehension like so:

```
print [i + 1 for i in ls if i % 2 != 0]
```

Note that, if your hope is to actually modify `ls`, the way you're doing it won't work. `i` is a *copy* of the value at any given point in `ls`, and modifying `i` will not modify anything within `ls`. If you wanted to actually change the values of `ls` in a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
    if ls[i] % 2 == 1:
        ls[i] += 1
```

or with a conditional expression:

```
ls = [i + 1 if i % 2 == 1 else i for i in ls]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
result = []
for i in ls:
    if(i%2!=0):
         i=i+1

    result.append(i)
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is literally just printing out each number one at a time. At no point are you creating a list. You have options.

You can use a list comprehension:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

yourlist = [i + 1 for i in ls if i % 2 != 0]

>>> print yourlist
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

[list comprehension tutorial](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Or with a for loop for the same result:

```
result = []

for i in ls:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        result.append(i + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To actually *modify* the list, use:

```
ls=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i, num in enumerate(ls):
     if num % 2 != 0:
         ls[i] += 1
print ls
```

Note that to update a list you must index it: `ls[i]` (Python indices start at 0). The `enumerate()` builtin function returns each index and the corresponding item from a list in turn.

Comment: He's using python 2.x - watch the print statement.

Comment: Also fair point - either it's been updated or my memory is poor, but I could've sworn `print()` threw an exception in 2.x.